I wanna start making scripts for my own Indie animation series, but can't find a good way to start it
I've been stumped for a few days on beginning my script for Space Hazard. I chose to begin writing with my biggest inspiration being Rodamrix. I already had a whole universe of ocs out there, but wanted to make my own series to tell their stories! HOWEVER, With so many options and different personal stories for each couple ocs, I... have no idea where to start. I've already planned to have two ocs, Cytrus and Willow, start off as our main protagonists. But with a whole script planned out in my head, that script would be enough for not even half of a pilot episode, unless I wanna keep it short. Unfortunately, I don't, and I have too many different timelines for how this story could go, I need to find a way to make both work out! In the end I still feel like the series would be way too short if I stuck with that same plot, Should I re-write it altogether? I'm really looking for some advice!

Can you elaborate on what it is you're looking for advice on? Are you asking for advice on how to choose which of your "timelines" to go with?

I'm mostly asking if I should stick with an existing timeline or make a new one, so yes.

It seems you have put the cart before the horse.

characters / universe first → difficult
story first → easy peasy

I recommend that you put everything that you have created away and give yourself a few weeks to brainstorm a completely new and fresh story that you want to tell without forcing this story to fit the world and characters you have already created. Try and be completely free and create a story that interests you, even if it is completely unrelated to what you have now. When you have a story, then try and come up with the characters and world that fit that story.

Where your story starts and where you start writing are rarely the same place.
Start writing - scenes, episodes, story arcs.  The more you write them the better you'll understand them, and you'll start to figure out what needs to be kept, what needs to be thrown out, or just is unnecessary for the audience to see.  Ordering and interweaving can happen in the second draft.
If you have an idea for an opening script, but it's too short, find a second plotline to interweave it with. This is often referred to as having an "A plot" and a "B plot", and while they're sometimes connected,  sometimes the relationships between them are entirely thematic.
Or just make your opening episode shorter - indie animation doesn't need to hold to the restrictions of professionally published productions.
RWBY's initial chapters were only ~5-10 min long, and that didn't stop it from becoming a rousing success.
